# User registration function too slow

Tags: php, time-limit-exceeded, pdo

I just wrote a PHP code to register users.

It's called through AJAX and it looks like it's too slow because it often sent me a .status = 0 that it means it took too much time to proceed.

If i replace my php function that register only by :

```
echo "Ok";
```

It always sent me a .status = 200

Could someone helps me to improve this file to make it faster ? I'm not used to code in PHP.

```
<?php

require_once('../config/database.php');
require_once('../config/functions.php');
$keywords = preg_split("/MyWebSite\//", getcwd());
$folder = explode('/', $keywords[1]);

if (!isset($_POST['login']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['password']) || !isset($_POST['password_check']))
{
    echo "missing some fields, did you try to edit my html?";
    die();
}
if (strlen($_POST['login']) < 5 || strlen($_POST['email']) == 0 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 5 || strlen($_POST['password_check']) < 5)
{
    echo "fieds badly filled";
    die();
}
if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password_check'])
{
    echo "passwords field aren't same";
    die();
}



try
{
    $db = new PDO($DB_DSN, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // to get an exception when caught an error :)
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Erreur !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$count_login = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM camagru_jgengo.user WHERE login = :login");
$count_login->bindValue(':login', $_POST['login']);
$count_login->execute();
if ($count_login->fetchColumn() > 0)
{
    echo "This username already taken";
    die();
}

$count_email = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM camagru_jgengo.user WHERE email = :email");
$count_email->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
$count_email->execute();
if ($count_email->fetchColumn() > 0)
{
    echo "This email already taken";
    die();
}



$insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO camagru_jgengo.user (email, login, password, admin, validate_link, created_at) VALUES (:email, :login, :password, 0, :validate_link, :created_at)');
$arr = array(
    ":login" => $_POST['login'],
    ":password" => hash_it($_POST['password']),
    ":email" => $_POST['email'],
    ":validate_link" => hash('md5', time()),
    ":created_at" => date('Y-m-d')
    );
$insert->execute($arr);

echo "Created!\n";

mail ($_POST['email'], "[Camagru] Active your account", "To active your account click that link : http://localhost:8080/".$folder[0]."/?p=activate&hash=".$arr[':validate_link']);

?>
```

Comment: this question is off topic. you need profiling here, not a code review. though it could be reviewed as well, made two times shorter.

Comment: how to make it two times shorter?

Comment: @Your Questions about performance improvement aren't really off-topic here, if asked specifically for that.

Comment: How many users exists in your `camagru_jgengo.user` table? Does it have the correct indexes set? (an index on `login` and one on `email`)

Comment: There is only 2 users at the moment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this question is not about performance improvement. It is about profiling. Or even debugging.

Comment: If your DB table currently only has 2 rows, then no matter how poorly indexed your tables are, I wouldn't see a scenario where the queries would be causing your script to timeout.  You need to debug this script to see where time is being spent.  Also `0` is not a valid HTTP status, so it is really unclear what you mean by status = 0.  Are you even sure this is a timeout problem?  Voting to close as this clearly is not working code.

Comment: You might simply have a very poorly performing web, database or smtp server.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`isset`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) can take multiple inputs, and fails if any of them is not set. So, the first `if` clause could become:

   ```
   if (!isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['password_check']))
   ```
2. I personally prefer using `!==` so that type juggling will not happen.

   ```
   if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_check'])
   ```
3. Instead of using `SELECT COUNT(*)` query to fetch existing username/email in your DB, you can instead set those columns to be `UNIQUE` and just go to the `INSERT` statement. The `INSERT` will fail with [error code **1062**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10775192/1190388).
4. Instead of using `camagru_jgengo.user` everywhere, you can set the `dbname` in the DSN string.
5. While not necessary, you can switch to using [`crypt()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) instead of md5 hashing. An MD5 has a higher collision chance, and since you are using it for sending emails with verification links. Using some form of salt will protect you from sending the same verification links to multiple users.

Comment: Hello, I could not have expect better than this answer :)

Thank you a lots !